# How can I know which resource is being edited in CQ.Extjs?

Tags: extjs, aem

I've got a dialog defined for a component:

```
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog" xtype="dialog">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <config jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel" title="FooTab">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <foo jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                text="Foo"
                                xtype="button"
                                name="./fooButton"
                                handler="function(b, e){/*what am I editing?*/};"/>
                </items>
            </config>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

How do I know which resource  is being edited by this dialog? Can I get the explicit path that is implicit in the "./" used in the name parameter? Is there some way to find it from the parameters (b = the button, e = the button click event) that are being passed to the button handler? If not, how can I get it into the button handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [button](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.Button) is on an dialog, and the [dialog](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Dialog) has the path.

So the following gives you the path:

```
b.findParentByType("dialog").path
```